# Mongoose: How to find documents by sub-collection's document property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m using Mongoose version 4.6.8 and MongoLab (MLab). I have a Mongoose schema called “Group” that has a collection of User subdocuments called “teachers”:

```
var GroupSchema = new Schema({
//…more properties here…//
teachers: [{
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
});
```

This is a document from the “groups” collection on MongoLab:

```
{
//…more properties here…//
    "teachers": [
        {
            "$oid": "5799a9c759feea9c208c004c"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is a document from the “users” collection on MongoLab:

```
{
//…more properties here…//
    "username": "bob"
}
```

But if I want to get a list of Groups that have a particular teacher (User) with the username of “bob”, this doesn’t work (the list of groups is empty):

```
Group.find({"teachers.username": "bob"}).exec(callback);
```

This also returns no items:

```
Group.find().where('teachers.username').equals('bob').exec(callback);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution in this case is to get a teacher’s groups through the User module instead of my first inclination which was to go through the Groups module. This makes sense because it is in line with how modern APIs represent a one-to-many relationship.

As an example, in Behance’s API, an endpoint for a user’s projects is:

```
GET /v2/users/user/projects
```

And a request to this endpoint (where the User’s username is “matiascorea”) would look like this:

```
https://api.behance.net/v2/users/matiascorea/projects?client_id=1234567890
```

So in my case, instead of finding the groups by teacher, I would need to simply find the User (teacher) by username, populate the teacher’s groups, and use them:

```
User.findOne({username: 'bob'})
     .populate('groups')
      .exec(callback);
```

And the API call for this would be:

```
GET /api/users/user/groups
```

And a request to this endpoint would look like this:

```
https://example.com/api/users/bob/groups
```

Answer (score 2):

Without some more knowledge of your set up (specifically whether you want anybody named Bob or a specific Bob whose id you could pick up first) - this might be some help although I think it would require you to flatten your teachers array to just their ID's, not single-key objects.

```
User.findById(<Id of Bob>, function(err, user){
    Group.find({}, function(err, groups){
      var t = groups.map(function(g){
        if(g['teachers'].indexOf(user.id))
          return g
      })
    // Do something with t
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, your answer led me to think of approaching it from a different angle - through the users module instead of the groups. I can't mark your answer as the accepted one because the groups can be populated from the User (which you would have known if I had put the groups property in my example code).

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use populate to do that.

**Try this:**

```
Group.find({})
     .populate({
         path : 'teachers' , 
         match : { username : "bob" }
      })
      .exec(callback);
```

`populate` will `populate` based on the `teachers` field (given `path`) and `match` will return only those who have `username` bob.

For more information on `mongoose populate options`, Please read [Mongoose populate documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: This is returning all groups whereas I want to get only the groups that have a teacher with the username of "Bob".

Comment: This is working in a similar case for me, are you sure it's not working? Can you double check?

Comment: Can you look into Mongoose populate documentation and see what's wrong. Specifically look into `match`. I'm sure this is right.

Comment: But as you said, your query will populate teachers (in all groups) who have a username of "bob", but this is not my use-case. I don't want to get teachers populated that match "bob", I want to get only the groups that have a teacher with the username of "bob".

Comment: i will try again, and see if i can get what you want.